# Cual es la función de RowDataPacket de MySQL en TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs, typescript

Estoy empezando con TypeScript, estoy observando un ejemplo de como obtener los resultados de una consulta utilizando MySQL2, funciona perfectamente, sin embargo no logro entender como funciona el RowDataPacket junto al resultado, tengo entendido que es un genérico, pero no logro comprenderlo bien, ojalá alguien me pueda explicar, gracias!

```
import mysql,{RowDataPacket} from "mysql2";

const conexion = mysqli.createConnection(.......);

conexion.query("SELECT * FROM....",(err, result) => {
       
        if (err) {console.log(err);}
    
        const rows = <RowDataPacket[]> result; //Esta parte no logro entender como funciona el  <RowDataPacket[]> junto al resultado
       
        rows.forEach(row=>{
            console.log(row);
        });
      }
    );
```

Comment: `RowDataPacket[]` es simplemente la interface que representa lo que te devuelve una query. Como una query puede devolverte diferentes resultados ( `RowDataPacket[]` | `RowDataPacket[][]` | `OkPacket` | `OkPacket[]` | `ResultSetHeader`),  es necesario el casting para especificar el objeto que esperas de acuerdo a la consulta que hiciste.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez tu comentario es una respuesta con todas las de la ley, te sugiero que lo pongas como respuesta y si gustas puedes añadir algunos enlaces a la documentación y algún [mre]. Saludos

Comment: Oh perfecto, ya entedí, según había leído que los casteos se realizaban con la palabra clave "as", pero estoy profundizando y ahora veo que la otra forma de hacerlo es con <typeB>A; Muchas gracias!